# Load trained Machine Learning model in javascript

Tags: javascript, python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, tensorflow.js

I am using sklearn in python to build/train some models (Random Forest Regressor, Kmeans, SVM, ...), and I would like to use those trained models in a webapp Javascript/html. Is there a way to do so?

I've seen that tensorflow.js allows to do such things with keras model. But it seems to me that TF/keras in python are limited to neural network.

I've also seen sklearn-porter, but it seems to be limited to some specific models (classification mostly). If anyone managed to use it, can they tell me more?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

As an option you can simply build [RESTfull API in Python](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/designing-a-restful-api-with-python-and-flask) (for instance using Flask). After it would be easy just request a prediction from Javascript.

There are few benefits for such approach:

- except the model, you still maybe need data preparation functions;
- you have to separated projects;
- with REST API you can easy add new version of the model;

Comment: Thanks for your message! I am already using AWS to do such a thing (API gateway + aws lambda), but the goal was to avoid calling the API... So I was wondering if any people knew other technique